# Emacs Python jedi suddenly failing

Tags: python, emacs, jedi

I have not used emacs for python coding for the last two weeks and by then it was all perfect, my set up worked perfectly, including jedi.

Two days ago I installed `virtualenvwrapper` in python (`pip install virtualenvwrapper`) and this is all that has changed from two weeks until today in my python installation. ***Nothing*** has changed in my emacs installation/set-up at all, absolutely nothing. Today, for the 1st time in two weeks I was going to start coding in python and as I typed `emacs test.py` in my terminal I obtained the following error messages in the `emacs` window:

```
Error (jedi): Failed to start Jedi EPC server.
*** You may need to run "M-x jedi:install-server". ***
This could solve the problem especially if you haven't run the command yet
since Jedi.el installation or update and if the server complains about
Python module imports.

deferred error : (error Server may raise an error : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/jediepcserver", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
import io
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
Referenced from: /Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

This is how I installed `jedi` a year ago:

**1-** I first followed the instructions here [jedi installation](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#troubleshooting). By the way, `epc, argparse, jedi` and `virtualenv` are already installed in python, of course.

**2-** The I read somewhere (I can't remember where) that the the jedi package at melpa is not updated. This sounded strange to me, but I decided to directly download `jedi` and also `python-environment` from github at: [jedi-github](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi) and [python-environment-github](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-python-environment). I placed them at `~/.emacs.d/emacs-jedi/` and `~/.emacs.d/emacs-python-environment/`

**3-** then set up `jedi` by doing:

```
;;Standard Jedi.el setting (read readme-jedi at .emacs.d/)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/emacs-jedi/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/emacs-python-environment/")
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
```

**4-** I run on emacs: `M-x jedi:install-server`

And done!, and this has worked for me during a year until today!.

Of course, as a 1st attempt to solve this I did exactly what the error message suggested and run (again) `M-x jedi:install-server`. Then I obtained the following error:

```
Running: pip install --upgrade /Users/javier/.emacs.d/emacs-jedi/...Done
deferred error : (error Process [/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/pip] exited abnormally : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip import main
File "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
File "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
import zipfile
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
import io
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
Referenced from: /Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

After this, and some other attempts, I decided to re-install everything, just using melpa. (i.e. following [jedi-installation](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#troubleshooting)). Then I run `M-x jedi:install-server` and got a very similar error message to the one described before:

```
Making completion list...
Running: pip install --upgrade /Users/javier/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-0.2.5/...Done
deferred error : (error Process [/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/pip] exited abnormally : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip import main
File "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
File "/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
import zipfile
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
import io
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
 Referenced from: /Users/javier/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

So to summarise, at this stage ***Nothing*** has changed in my `.emacs` file or my `.emacs.d` directory from the original installation.

All changes done to my python package installation during the last two days are simply the installation of `virtualenvwrapper`. At this stage I am quite lost . ***ANY*** help is much appreciated.

THANKS in advance for your time.

Comment: It looks like python 2.7.10 issue. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40241

Comment: Hy syohex. Thanks for the help. Actually during the installation of `virtualenvwrapper` it automatically updated to 2.7.10, so certainly might be this. Emacs+python has given me many headaches! :) . I´ll end up moving to sublime. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem to this a while back. The problem was that Python could not find my installation of jedi. Check if rope works in emacs. It can be installed with pip the same way as jedi. If it does work, just move the jedi package to the same directory as rope. This is how I sorted the problem out anyway.

Comment: I decided to move to sublime because of sublimeREPL, wich allows a wonderful sublime text + IPython interaction. Then discover that this interaction does not work with IPython 3. versions...the world of text editors can be a pain...